# Variation of finding the number of binary trees for a given n number of keys

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, combinations

Given a list `A` of `n` distinct keys, how many binary search trees can be formed such that in
any subtree, the difference between the numbers of nodes in its left and right subtrees is at
most by one?

The recurrence relation for the number of binary search trees **without** the condition is

```
f(1) = f(0) = 1;
Let total_trees = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<= n; ++i)
   total_trees += f(i-1) * f(n-i)
```

Can anyone help with the variation?

My try (which is wrong):

```
f(1) = f(0) = 1;
Let total_trees = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<= n; ++i)
   total_trees += f(i) * f(i-1)
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: @Adam This is not a homework. I'm preparing for an exam. If necessary I will provide a link that says this question is for practice.

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Answer (score 2):

Let's all the keys are in linear array.
If number of keys is even, you have 2 variants of root - 2 central elements.
For odd number of keys there is only one variant with central element as root to fulfill the condition. So recursion looks like:

f(1) = f(0) = 1

f(2*k) = f(k-1) * f(k+1) + f(k+1) * f(k-1) = 2 * f(k-1) * f(k+1)

f(2*k+1) = f(k)*f(k)